# Split string by whitespaces, ignoring escaped whitespaces

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split, literals

I've been using the [Percentage Strings Literal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) to convert strings like `"one two three four\ five"` into an array.

```
%w(one two three four\ five)
```

returns:

```
["one", "two", "three", "four five"]
```

Now I want to do this dynamically, so can use Literals anymore.

Which regex pattern can I use to convert my string above into an array?

I'm looking for a regex pattern to place into a ruby split method that will take `"one two three four\ five"` and return `["one", "two", "three", "four five"]`.

Note: I only want to split by whitespaces that **aren't escaped**, like above. Four and Five were combined into the same string because the whitespace that separated them was escaped.

Comment: It is not very clear, but you may try either `.split(/(?<!\\)\s+/)` or `.scan(/(?:[^\\\s]|\\.)+/)`. I'd rather prefer the `scan` option.

Comment: Apologies if its not clear, I'll update with more info now. I couldn't get your examples to output what I want - I'll improve the clarity of my question - Thanks

Comment: Look [here](https://ideone.com/VUd5GV).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew suggestions is correct. Try it here: http://rubular.com/r/NPxmm8PfqB

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your examples do work, apologies, I was running them with double quotes (`""`) rather than single - my bad!

Comment: Is there a way we can get rid of the \ in the Four\ Five? (without using `gsub` afterwards). If so put your comment as an answer and i'll mark it correct.

Comment: No, if you match it, it will be part of the match.

Comment: Just use `shellwords` feature.

Comment: It is a duplicate, good spot - the original is recent too. I'll sort it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strings have no escape sequences, you may use a splitting approach with

```
.split(/(?<!\\)\s+/)
```

Here, `(?<!\\)\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces (`\s+`) that are not preceded with `\`.

If your strings may contain escape sequences, a *matching* approach is preferable as it is more reliable:

```
.scan(/(?:[^\\\s]|\\.)+/)
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/VUd5GV).

It will match 1 or more characters other than `\` and whitespace (with `[^\\\s]`) and any escape sequence (matched with `\\.`, a backslash + any char other than line break chars).

To get rid of `\` symbols, you will have to use a `gsub` later.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
require 'shellwords'

'one two three four\ five'.shellsplit
# => ["one", "two", "three", "four five"]
```

No need for a regexp.

Comment: This is great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(?<!\\)\s+
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/MOtysr/1)

sample:

```
a='one two three four\ five';
b=a.split(/(?<!\\)\s+/);
print(b);
```

[Run here](http://ideone.com/NzLEDW)

Comment: Thanks for the examples :)